# Get multiple async urls data, then make action on result (tampermonkey script)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm somewhat new to JS so be patient please. I'm trying to create a Tampermonkey (greasyfork) script for a website.

Steps should be:

- Check if user is logged in
- If yes, go to his "movie ratings" page and load all (for example 40) pages, get their HTML, extract movie ratings and store them in LocalStorage
- When that is finished, continue with another code (adding column to table etc...)

Right now it works but it's Synchronous. So when data are not in LocalStorage it will load each page really slowly (1page +- 1second, typical is 50-100 pages) and user waits and doesn't know if anything is happening. My "popup" function doesn't work with "async: false" but does with "async: true".

But when I use async, it won't wait and the code is not behaving like I would like it to have.

If you tell me "just do a Promise, just do a callback" I wouldn't know what to do. I've googled for a day and didn't find anything that works.

I learn by working code examples/modifications.

My code for now (simplified)

```js
(() => {
    class Csfd {

        constructor(csfdPage) {
            this.csfdPage = csfdPage;
            this.stars = {};  // dict which is then saved as json to LocalStorage
            this.userUrl = undefined;
        }

        getCurrentUser() { ... }
        addRatingsColumn() { ... }

        REFRESH_RATINGS() {
            // Load user ratings...
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: this.userRatingsUrl,  // page when pagination of all ratings starts
                async: false
            }).done((data) => {
                this.processRatingsPage(data);
            });

        }

        processRatingsPage(dataHTML) {
            var $stars = this.stars;
            $(dataHTML).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
                let starsRatings .... // simplified line, get the data of each rating row
                $stars[filmURL] = starsRating;
            });

            // Check if there is next page
            let nextPaginationURL = $(dataHTML).find("a.page-next").attr("href");
            if (nextPaginationURL) {
                // Next page exists, fetch it and repeat, add new ratings to `this.stars`
                this.loadPage(nextPaginationURL);
            } else {
                // No next page, finish...
                this.finishRefresh();
            }
        }
        
        loadPage(url) {
            let foundMatch = url.match(new RegExp("page=(.*)$"));
            let currentNum = 1;
            if (foundMatch.length == 2) {
                currentNum = foundMatch[1];
            }
            
            console.log(`${SCRIPTNAME} - Loading... ${currentNum}/${this.endPageNum}`);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                async: false
            }).done((data) => {
                this.processRatingsPage(data);
            });
        }

        finishRefresh() {
            this.exportRatings();  // export JSON stringify to LocalStorage
        }
    }
    
    // SCRIPT START
    csfd.userUrl = csfd.getCurrentUser();

    // If logged in, do some stuff
    if (csfd.userUrl !== undefined) {
        
        // If movie ratings not loaded in LocalStorage...
        csfd.REFRESH_RATINGS();
   }
   
   // --> THIS IS CALLED BEFORE REFRESH_RATINGS ENDS IF I DO async: true
   if (Object.keys(this.stars).length != 0) {
       // Continue after movie ratings are loaded
       csfd.addRatingsColumn();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your ajax call in a `Promise` which is resolved when the call returns. Something like this:

```
(async () => {
       ...

        async REFRESH_RATINGS() {
            // Load user ratings...
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
               $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: this.userRatingsUrl,  // page when pagination of all ratings starts
                  async: true
               }).done((data) => {
                  this.processRatingsPage(data);
                  resolve();
               })
            });
        }

       ...

       if (csfd.userUrl !== undefined) {
          // If movie ratings not loaded in LocalStorage...
          await csfd.REFRESH_RATINGS();
       }
       ...
```

Comment: I've tried to implement it and test some things but to no avail. When those pages are loading, browser is frozen, it does it one after another so - it's behaving like non-async code. Here's my newest commit. https://github.com/SonGokussj4/greasyfork-scripts/blob/async-test/csfd-compare.js

Comment: So not frozen anymore, I've made one function (loadPage) async, that helped. But it wouldn't wait so... I've made a button that calls this and I won't refresh the data on main function run anymore. Not sure how to do that, it's weird. So now it's still working, almost, like non-async.